# socket.io - connect to news feed throws an error of Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, rss

Please find below my code:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>

    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var socket = io.connect('http://economictimes.feedsportal.com/c/33041/f/534037/index.rss');

      //var socket = io.set('origins', 'http://economictimes.feedsportal.com/c/33041/f/534037/index.rss');

      socket.on('connect', function(data){
        setStatus('connected');
        socket.emit('subscribe', {channel:'realtime'});
      });

      socket.on('reconnecting', function(data){
        setStatus('reconnecting');
      });

      socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log('received a message: ', data);
        addMessage(data);
      });

      function addMessage(data) {
          $('#online').html(data);
      }

      function setStatus(msg) {
          console.log('Connection Status : ' + msg);
      }


    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table>
      <tr style="width:100%; height: 200px;"> 
        <td align="center" style="width: 30%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid #000;" >
            <p id="online" style="font-size: 100px;">0</p>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The issue is I am getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present` error on `chrome`. Even I tried in `chrome` with `--disable-web-security` but the same error comes.

I need to connect to the news feed `http://economictimes.feedsportal.com/c/33041/f/534037/index.rss` with `socket.io`. I am planning to build news portal from multiple news feed using `html5`, `javascript`, `jquery`, `websocket` and `socket.io`.

**How do I connect to news feed with `socket.io` ???**